# Terminate a waiting thread

Tags: winapi

I have a win32 thread, waiting for a mutex with the 'WaitForSingleObject' function. 
Is it safe to terminate the thread (with TerminateThread)?
In the microsoft doc, they say TerminateThread is dangerous, but is it in this situation?
Thank you

Comment: It is more dangerous, the mutex state doesn't get restored properly.  Next the program will fail with WAIT_ABANDONED. That a mutex can report such unrecoverable synchronization state corruption is pretty useful.

Comment: this is always not safe call `TerminateThread`, because thread already can stop wait and begin do another job. if you terminate it when it for example in critical section (say allocate or free from heap) - all process can freeze after this. call `TerminateThread` always bad solution, use `WaitForSingleObjectEx` and send apc for thread or more better - use `ZwWaitForSingleObject` and you can send alert to thread in this case

Comment: [Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=91811).

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue? And is there the answer available for you? Please feel free to mark it, or add your answer then mark yourself to help people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `TerminateThread` always bad and never safe. when you call `TerminateThread` thread can already finish wait and begin do something else. possible for example it will be allocate or free memory from heap, so inside critical section. if terminate thread in this moment - critical section never will be free and all process hang, thread by thread, on next heap call. in any case some thread resources not will be free, until exit of process.

however never really need terminate thread. possible found clean solution. you can use [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobjectex) for wait in alertable state, and if you want break this wait, you need call `QueueUserAPC` (with some dummy callback) instead `TerminateThread`

```
VOID NTAPI DummyApcFunc(_In_ ULONG_PTR /*Parameter*/){
}
//----------------
    switch (WaitForSingleObjectEx(hMutex, INFINITE, TRUE))
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    case WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
        DbgPrint("mutex acquired\n");
        break;
    case STATUS_USER_APC:
        DbgPrint("stop wait for mutex\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_FAILED:
        GetLastError();
        break;
    default:
        __debugbreak();
    }
//----------------
QueueUserAPC(DummyApcFunc, hThread, 0);
```

or even more better - use [`ZwWaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-zwwaitforsingleobject) - in this case you can break thread wait by alert, not need dummy apc

```
    switch (ZwWaitForSingleObject(hMutex, TRUE, 0))
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    case WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
        DbgPrint("mutex acquired\n");
        break;
    case STATUS_USER_APC:
    case STATUS_ALERTED:
        DbgPrint("stop wait for mutex\n");
        break;
    default:
        __debugbreak();
    }
//------------------------------
ZwAlertThread(hThread);
```